# Connect sails.io with an iOS swift app

Tags: ios, swift, sails.js, sails.io.js

I'm trying to connect a simple iOS app to a sails.js API. The iOS app is written in swift. The version of sails is the 0.11

For the web-socket management I use https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-swift

```
class Communicate: UIViewController {

let socket = SocketIOClient(socketURL: "localhost:2000")

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.addHandlers()
    self.socket.connect()
}

func addHandlers() {

    socket.on("connect") {data, ack in
        print("socket connected !") // This is working

        self.socket.emit("get", ["url": "/device"]) // I get the sails error
    }

}
}
```

On the sails.js console, I get the following error:

```
verbose: Receiving incoming message from Socket.io:  { url: '/device?__sails_io_sdk_version=0.11.0&__sails_io_sdk_platform=iOS&__sails_io_sdk_language=fr' }

error: Error (SAILS:HOOK:SOCKETS:PARSE_VIRTUAL_REQ):: Failed to parse incoming socket.io request.

details: 'Sails v0.11.x is not compatible with the socket.io/sails.io.js client SDK version you are using (0.9.0). Please see the v0.11 migration guide on http://sailsjs.org for more information.' }
```

I probably do something wrong to imitate the behaviour of sails.io, but I don't know how to achieve it.

Thank by advance for your help.

Comment: Did you get a more formal solution to this?

Comment: I didn't found a definitive "clean" solution... But yours worked!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of changing the server, you can connect parameters to tell the server that you comply with v0.11.0 semantics with:

```
self.socket = SocketIOClient(socketURL: baseWebSocketServerURL, options: 
[SocketIOClientOption.ConnectParams(["__sails_io_sdk_version":"0.11.0"])])
```

I think that this is a better solution than hacking the server and breaking semantic version checking for other clients.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is not the best solution.
But if you go node_modules\sails\node_modules\sails-hook-sockets\lib\parse-sdk-metadata.js
change 
handshake.query[SDK_META_PARAMS.version] = '0.9.0';
to '0.11.0'
This can solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

In case the other answer doesn't work for you, give this a shot:

```
    let socket = SocketIOClient(socketURL: URL(string: "http://yoursailsserver.com:1337)")!, config: [.log(true), .forcePolling(true), .connectParams(["__sails_io_sdk_version":"0.11.0"])])
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add `?__sails_io_sdk_version=0.11.0` at the end of your socket url

Example:
`http://www.example.com:port/?__sails_io_sdk_version=0.11.0`